# Can I notify a BehaviorProcessor from inside a RxJava stream?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2, observer-pattern

I would like to get your feedback on the code below.
I'm wondering if it's safe to call `currentSession.onNext(result.session)`
from inside the `SessionManager.signIn` stream.

My first intuition is to say `NO` because of multithreading and synchronization issues, meaning, based on this code, I could be calling `currentSession.onNext(result.session)` from different threads.

Here is the code, please let me know what you think! Thanks

SessionManager which is a singleton

```
@Singleton
class SessionManager @Inject constructor(
    private val sessionService: SessionService,
){

    val currentSession = BehaviorProcessor.create<Session>()

    fun signIn(login: String, password: String): Single<Boolean> =
        sessionService.signIn(login, password)
            .doOnNext(result -> 
                if (session is Success) {
                   currentSession.onNext(result.session)
                }
            ).map { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Success -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

HomeView which is a random View subscribing to the SessionManager's signIn stream

```
class HomeView(val context: Context) : View(context) {

        @Inject
        lateinit var sessionManager: SessionManager

        private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()

            disposables.add(sessionManager.signIn("username", "password")
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { result ->
                    textView.text = if (result) "Success" else "Fail"
                })
        }

        override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow()
            disposables.clear()
        }
    }
```

A random View observing the `currentSession` from `SessionManager`

```
class RandomView(val context: Context) : View(context) {

        @Inject
        lateinit var sessionManager: SessionManager

        private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()

            disposables.add(sessionManager.currentSession
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { session -> userTextView.text = session.userName })
        }

        override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow()
            disposables.clear()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of BehaviorProcessor](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/BehaviorProcessor.html) says:

> Calling onNext(Object), offer(Object), onError(Throwable) and onComplete() is required to be serialized (called from the same thread or called non-overlappingly from different threads through external means of serialization). **The FlowableProcessor.toSerialized() method available to all FlowableProcessors provides such serialization and also protects against reentrance** (i.e., when a downstream Subscriber consuming this processor also wants to call onNext(Object) on this processor recursively).

So if you define it like this:

```
val currentSession = BehaviorProcessor.create<Session>().toSerialized()
```

then you can safely call `onNext` from any thread, it will not cause any synchronisation problems.

**Notes:**

I agree that the update of the processor should be in a `doOnNext` instead of the `map`.

I think it would be better to use a `Completable` instead of a `Single<Boolean>`, and use Rx errors to indicate what prevented signing in. You should also define the error handlers in the `subscribe` methods.

Comment: Makes sense - Thanks!

I found a good article about it afterwards:
https://proandroiddev.com/state-propagation-in-android-with-rxjava-subjects-81db49a0dd8e

They mention exactly what you say in your response.

Thank you also for the side notes, I voluntary kept the stream as simple as possible to avoid noises but your recommendations are helpful!